# Couldn't install ghcup installer for Haskell on my MacOS machine

Tags: haskell

Currently, I'm trying to learn pure functional programming language, which is Haskell. I'm trying to install Haskell compiler, I have followed the instructions to install `ghcup` on my MacOS by following command: 
`curl https://get-ghcup.haskell.org -sSf | sh`
But I couldn't install it, it prompted errors like these:

`Following commands are required, but missing, please install:  xz
"ghcup upgrade" failed!`

`Following commands are required, but missing, please install:  xz`

I hope somebody picks up this question and helps me get this out, thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to install `xz`, for example with `brew install xz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`xz`** [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) is a (de)compression tool. It is sometimes used to send data in a compressed form over a network.

You can install `xz` on a Mac OS X system with:

```
brew install xz
```

Given of course you first [installed `brew` on your machine [brew.sh]](https://brew.sh/).